# How to convert Object into Array in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nodes, es6-modules

I want to convert the collection of object values to array.

`var data = [{"phrase": "hello"},{"phrase": "world"}]`

I want to convert like `data = ["hello","world"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. ```data.map(obj => Object.values(obj)[0].phrase);``` works for me